# How to replace a value in SQLdata table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table name Image there is two column with Name & Url all the rows in url having same value and starting in that some values are same i want to update the in one query...

For example...

```
http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2854/10380193164_9b65e4c5ed_n.jpg
```

I want to replace this and want to add a folder name like pages after the .com/

```
http://farm3.staticflickr.com/pages/2854/10380193164_9b65e4c5ed_n.jpg
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

```
declare @var nvarchar(max)='http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2854/10380193164_9b65e4c5ed_n.jpg'

select REPLACE(@var, '.com/', '.com/pages/')
```

i.e. for selecting from a table, try

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(ColumnName, '.com/', '.com/pages/') as ColumnName 
FROM YourTable
```

To UPDATE table, use query:

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET ColumnName=REPLACE(ColumnName, '.com/', '.com/pages/')
```

Comment: Sir, I want to find http://farm3.staticflickr.com/ in all rows and after that replace with http://farm3.staticflickr.com/pages/

Comment: @skgacharya Did you try to execute the query above? The REPLACE function does what you want to achieve. To perform the query on all the rows, just do: `SELECT REPLACE(myURLColumn, '.com/', '.com/pages/') as MyURLColumnReplaced FROM MyTable`

Comment: @AlbertoSolano I want to replace this url link in all rows of table not in single record and by your query not even a row is updating...

Comment: @skgacharya Just because it's a SELECT. Perform an [UPDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) with REPLACE instead.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano its showing data with replace value but its not replacing in database... after using its showing old data...

Answer (score 0):

@skgacharya, I hope the query for update was already given by @Techdo. Try this...

```
UPDATE YourTable_name 
SET yourURLColumn_Name=REPLACE(yourURLColumn_Name, '.com/', '.com/pages/')
```